# Raphael JS Set ID for paper.set object

Tags: raphael

I want to provide an ID to a SET object. Any idea how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my knowledge there is only one way ....
extend the Raphael.st

```
Raphael.st.setID = function(id){
this.id = id;
}

var yourset = paper.set(); 
    yourset.setID(id); //give the id you want

then try -> yourset.id;
```

I hope it works for you ....

Comment: Setting of ID works. I have few elements in the Set. I want to hide some elements by accessing the Set with ID. at present that is not happening. I know that Paper.getById(yourset.id) wont returns the Set. How can i access the elements inside a set by using its ID..

Comment: The raphael set is actually an extension of the array .... access elements of a set like an array i.e. set[0],set[1],set[2] .... apply native array functions like splice() etc and extended functions from Raphael like exclude() ....